# How to find every number that a certain digit is present in

Tags: python

I'm wondering how to list all the numbers that contain a certain digit (from an input), how do I do this?

I've tried looking on StackOverflow already, and tried some code from answers, but it hasn't worked, I believe there's something I've done wrong, please help?

My code:

```
a = int(input("Search for: "))
b = int(input("In range up to: "))
numbers = range(0, b)
expected_numbers = [i for i in numbers if a in str(i)]
print(expected_numbers)
```

This is the error message I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "program.py", line 4, in <module>
    expected_numbers=[i for i in numbers if a in str(i)]
  File "program.py", line 4, in <listcomp>
    expected_numbers=[i for i in numbers if a in str(i)]
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not int
```

I appreciate any help, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here.

```
a = input()
b = int(input())
expected_numbers = [i for i in range(b) if a in str(i)]
print(expected_numbers)
```

Actually you are taking "a" as integer. Rest everything is correct.

If you want to print it than just modify the last line.

```
for i in expected_numbers:
    print(i,"contains",a)
```

You will get desired result.

Comment: Your optimized version does not work correctly. Just try `a=13` and `b=2000` and you will get results, which do not contain `13` in.

Comment: A digit is a single value which ranges between (0-9) . The case you are saying.. its a number. In question digit word is mentioned.

Comment: Fair anough, my bad, but then consider the case `a=1, b=20`, you still miss all the numbers `12, 13, 14, ..., 19` in the solution.

Comment: Yes. Got it now. I will try to see these cases and post it again with right answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, but I am also trying to print out the output like this:

Search for: 2

In range up to: 12

2 contains 2

12 contains 2

Any ideas?

Comment: See it in the answer the way for it.

Answer (score 1):

just a small error, convert your variable `a` into `str`.

```
`expected_numbers = [i for i in range(b) if str(a) in str(i)]`
```

Also PS: Use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to learn about formatting options on StackOverflow. :)